# How do I find the equation of the circle, given the points (0,2) (3,3) (7,1)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

Please just explain it in the simplest way. Thank you! Show also the answer you've come up with.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297213/finding-center-and-radius-of-circumscribed-triangle/2297216#2297216

Comment: HINT

Two of the six equations with six unknowns are:

$$x_o+R\cos(\theta_a) =x_a$$

and

$$y_o+R\sin(\theta_a) =y_a$$

The 3 key unknowns (origin coordinates and circle radius) are in the above equation. With the 4 remaining equations involving the other two polar angles, you have the closure that you need.

Comment: how do the given points relate to the circle?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, let $A=(0,2), B=(3,3) $ and $C=(7,1)$. Find the equation of the perpendicular bisectors of chords $AB$ and $BC$.

Then with the 2 perpendicular bisector found, find their common point of intersection, this will give you the centre of the circle.

Once the centre of the circle is found, it should be easy to determine the radius.

Comment: I got the center (9, 10) but when I sketched it on the graph, it looks too far

Comment: @Janine too far from the center of the circle or too far from the other points?  Consider the unit circle centered at zero with radius $1$... The three points $(1,0),(\cos(0.01),\sin(0.01)),(\cos(0.02),\sin(0.02))$ are all clustered right around the point $(1,0)$... are you thinking that center is "too far" as well?  Although I haven't checked your answer, your reasoning for doubting your answer isn't very well explained.

Comment: The center that I got is too far from the other points

Comment: @Janine The center is $(3,-2)$. Please check your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 $(x,y)$ pairs that belong to the circunference: $(0,2);(3,3);(7,1)$. That way, it is possible for you to build a system of equations where the variables are $a,b$ and $R$ belong to the circle equation:

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(x-0)^2+(y-2)^2=R^2 \\ 
(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2=R^2 \\ 
(x-7)^2+(y-1)^2=R^2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $(a,b) $ be the center. then

$$a^2+(b-2)^2=(a-3)^2+(b-3)^2$$
$$=(a-7)^2+(b-1)^2=R^2$$

Solve to get $a,b,R $.

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, we have three equations $$(x_1-X)^2+(y_1-Y)^2-R^2=0 \tag 1$$ $$(x_2-X)^2+(y_2-Y)^2-R^2=0 \tag 2$$ $$(x_3-X)^2+(y_3-Y)^2-R^2=0 \tag 3$$ Subtrcat $(1)$ from $(2)$ and $(1)$ from $(3)$ and simplify. You should get $$2X(x_1-x_2)+2Y(y_1-y_2)=(x_1^2+y_1^2)-(x_2^2+y_2^2) \tag 4$$ $$2X(x_1-x_3)+2Y(y_1-y_3)=(x_1^2+y_1^2)-(x_3^2+y_3^2) \tag 5$$ Then two linear equations in $X,Y$. Solve them and, when done, replace in $(1)$, $(2)$ or $(3)$ to get $R^2$.